# Countdown Clock to a Specific Time

Tags: javascript, jquery, flipclock

I am using [FlipClock.js](http://flipclockjs.com/) to have a countdown clock till new year day. I want to change this to countdown to 8am local time on the first. I am a bit confused as to how to do this.

Here is the script I am currently using:

```
var clock;
$(function() {
  var currentDate = new Date();
  var futureDate  = new Date(currentDate.getFullYear() + 1, 0, 1);
  var diff = futureDate.getTime() / 1000 - currentDate.getTime() / 1000;
  clock = $('.clock').FlipClock(diff, {
    clockFace: 'DailyCounter',
    countdown: true
  });
});
```

***EDIT***

I tried changing my code to this:

```
var clock;
$(function() {
  var currentDate = new Date();
  var futureDate  = new Date(Date.UTC(2014, 0, 01, 08, 0, 0));
  var diff = futureDate.getTime() / 1000 - currentDate.getTime() / 1000;
  clock = $('.clock').FlipClock(diff, {
    clockFace: 'DailyCounter',
    countdown: true
  });
});
```

This line

```
var futureDate  = new Date(currentDate.getFullYear() + 1, 0, 1);
```

was changed to this line:

```
var futureDate  = new Date(Date.UTC(2014, 0, 01, 08, 0, 0));
```

When I did this it added one hour to the countdown clock. It should of added more since the time was 12am to 8am. What did I do wrong and how do I correct it?

Comment: All you have to do is modify the `futureDate` variable. `"8am local time on the first."` is a relative term - you'll have to create a date object specifying the exact date & time you want it to represent.

Comment: @Lix - Please see my edit for what I have attempted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `Lix` said you should modify the `futureDate`. If you have a problem with that my advice is to read about predefined `Date` object in Javascript language. [Here is a good reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

One of the valid definition of a `Date` object is shown below:

```
new Date(year, month [, day, hour, minute, second, millisecond]);
```

After you succesfully found next year (`currentDate.getFullYear() + 1`) all you have to do is to properly fill the rest of the parameters.

**Beware** - in Javascript `Date` object only a month is counted counterintuitive relative to the rest: `0-11`.

Comment: Thank you for the information. See my edit for what I attempted.

Comment: I told you to use the definition which I wrote in my answer. If you write a parameter hour as 8 it will work correctly. Your new version doesn't include timezone.